# How to query the Active directory for a users email using the UPN\username from a domain joined machine

Tags: authentication, active-directory, ldap

How to query the Active directory for a users email using the UPN\username from a domain joined machine?

Answer (score 0):

using powershell

```
Get-ADUser -Filter { UserPrincipalName -eq "username@yourdomain.com" } -Properties EmailAddress | Select-Object Name, EmailAddress
```

or

```
Get-ADUser -Filter { SAMAccountName -eq "username" } -Properties EmailAddress | Select-Object Name, EmailAddress
```